# F# how to write a function which provides a counter number in serial order

Tags: f#

So if you go to a bank there is a device from which you can pull a number out.

I want to write a function like that. So everytime this function is called we get a next number in the series.

So if this function is called first time, we get 1. second time we get 2.... so on and so forth.

this is what I have written so far

```
let X =
    let myseq = seq {1 .. 100}
    let GetValue = 
        Seq.head (Seq.take 1 myseq)
    GetValue;;

 let p = X;;
 p;;
 p;;
 p;;
```

But it always return 1. My hope was that since the sequence is a closure, everytime I do a take, I will get the next number.

I also tried this

```
let X =
    let mutable i = 1
    let GetValue = 
        i <- i + 1
        i
    GetValue;;

 let p = X;;
 p;;
 p;;
 p;;
```

This one only prints 2...

Comment: You need to make GetValue a function.

Comment: It is considered bad practice to use mutable in a functional language. If you want to use mutable types, try c#. The spirit of "functions" are to take one input and give one output. If they modify something, that is known as a side-effect and is frowned upon. So, in short, iterators are not supported. Even a simple for loop is done through recursion.

Comment: @PhillipScottGivens - F# actually has quite strong support for imperative constructs including for / while and I don't see anything particularly wrong with this code.

Comment: This scenario is a specific example of a more general `multiple consumer and single producer`. I would suggest to use `MailboxProcessor` for such cases, which would allow you to get rid of mutability - as the state can passed as parameter to the message loop - and it will also give you concurrency such that multiple consumers at the same time can ask for a value and still get unique value

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just for a reference, if you wanted a version that uses sequences (just like the first approach in your question), you can do that using the `IEnumerable` interface:

```
let factory = 
  // Infinite sequence of numbers & get enumerator
  let numbers = Seq.initInfinite id
  let en = numbers.GetEnumerator()
  fun () -> 
    // Move to the next number and return it
    en.MoveNext() |> ignore
    en.Current
```

It behaves the same way as `factory` in Daniel's answer. This still uses mutable state - but it is hidden inside the enumerator (which keeps the current state of the sequence between `MoveNext` calls).

In this simple case, I'd use Daniel's version, but the above might be handy if you want to iterate over something else than just increasing numbers.

Comment: ya, i was also thinking that an infinite seq would be good, there is even a good chance you might be able to do it with sequence comprehensions.

Comment: You could write a recursive sequence expression to generate `numbers`, but I guess `initInfinite` is simpler in this case :-)

Answer (score 9):

You have to return a function. And to it, you have to pass something every time, i.e. your `+1` has to be deferred.

```
let factory = 
    let counter = ref 0
    fun () -> 
        counter.Value <- !counter + 1
        !counter
```

and now you get

```
> factory();;
val it : int = 1
> factory();;
val it : int = 2
```

doing it this way has the nice side-effect, that you completely hide the mutable reference cell inside the function and thus there is no way to somehow tamper with your counter.

Comment: Could also do `incr counter`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to move the variable outside the declaration.  You also need to declare a function so that it gets evaluated each time it is called.

```
let mutable i = 1
let X() =
    i <- i + 1
    i
```

This ensures that the function is called each time and that the variable is correctly incremented.